# Heroku Postgres Datababe automatically cleared or reset

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

Currently facing an issue for which I am not able to find any solution.
I am a beginner so I apologise if my questions look strange for some of you.
I explain you my issue :
I deployed my first application on Heroku with the following :

- Front Angular
- Back Spring + database Postgres
  It seems that every 24 hours or even less than 24 hours, my data from heroku postgres are automatically cleared, or basically my database is reset.
  Does anyone has a reason of that ? Is it linked to the way Heroku postgres is working ?

Thanks for your feedback

**Extrait from application.properties**

> spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
> spring.datasource.url=${DB_URL}
> spring.datasource.username= ${DB_USER}
> spring.datasource.password= ${DB_PASS}
> spring.jpa.show-sql=true
> spring.jpa.format_sql=true
> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
> spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physicals trategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
> spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
> spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
> spring.datasource.maxActive=10
> spring.datasource.maxIdle=5
> spring.datasource.minIdle=2
> spring.datasource.initialSize=5
> spring.datasource.removeAbandoned=true

Comment: Are you _entirely_ sure you're using Postgres? This sounds very much like what happens when you use SQLite on Heroku. Please show your relevant database configuration settings.

Comment: That simply means you have a database provisioned. Your code won't magically use it. Again, please show your relevant database configuration settings.

Comment: Hi Chris I may misunderstood, I just started the dev a few months ago. When you ask me for the database configuration settings, you mean my application.properties files ?

Comment: Please edit that into your question, formatted as a code block. It is very hard to read in comments, and comments are meant only for temporary content. They can be deleted at any time for any reason. Also, do you have any other properties files, e.g. `applicaton-local.properties`?

Comment: I post my application.properties. I don't have any applicaton-local.properties

Comment: Still no answer on that point ?

Comment: I don't know much about Spring, but I _do_ know Heroku. It's very likely that you are using SQLite. I'm not sure what else might govern that in the Spring world besides your `application.properties`, but I suggest you dig into that.